# Why is my date object not displaying properly in VSCode

Tags: javascript, date, object, visual-studio-code

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, dob) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
}

console.log(person1);
const person2 = new Person('Mary', 'Jane', '12-04-1998');

console.log(person2.dob)
```

The console output in **Chrome** gives me:

```
Person
dob: Fri Nov 02 1990 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time) {}
firstName: "John"
lastName: "Doe"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Person(firstName, lastName, dob)
__proto__: Object

Fri Dec 04 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
```

But in **VSCode** the terminal outputs:

```
Person {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  dob: 1990-11-**01**T16:00:00.000Z
}
1998-12-**03**T16:00:00.000Z
```

Why are the numbers in the date different and what is the T?

Comment: I think you need to read up the documentation about this: https://javascript.info/date#:~:text=The%20string%20format%20should%20be,%3A%20year%2Dmonth%2Dday for the datetime property

Comment: `'12-04-1998'` isn't a string format that the `Date` constructor is specified to correctly parse, so if you get anything but `Invalid Date` for it, your code is relying on the JavaScript engine *"fall[ing] back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats"* ([link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse)) which can vary by JavaScript engine. See the linked question's answers for what that format is and what you can do.

Comment: The `T` is the standard delimiter between the date and time in an ISO date-time

Comment: @arslan2012 The timezone is the `Z` at the end. `T` is just a delimiter.